# Making an executable bash file run when clicked

Tags: macos, bash, executable

I have a bash file that does some file manipulation. I don't want to have to open the terminal every time I run it. Is there a way to make the program run when I double click it? (Like a windows .exe file)

Thanks

Comment: Zifei Tong answered your question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can add a ".command" extension to the filename -- then double-clicking it will automatically open Terminal and run the script in a new window.  Note: this assumes you still want to watch/interact with the script via a Terminal interface; if you want to avoid this as well, wrapping the script with Platypus, AppleScript, or Automator (as Zifei and Ned suggest) would be better options.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. At the time, I just set the default application to the Terminal

Answer (score 12):

What you need is  [`Platypus`](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus).

> Platypus is a developer tool for the Mac OS X operating system. It can be used to create native, flawlessly integrated Mac OS X applications from interpreted scripts such as shell scripts or Perl and Python programs. This is done by wrapping the script in an application bundle directory structure along with an executable binary that runs the script.

Comment: maybe this is only for linuz, but isn't there a way to change the file to make it an executable?

Comment: @jamesatha: Mark the file executable via `chmod +x file` and then make sure the first line reads `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: That just makes a file executable in a shell.  It does not make it something that can be clicked to launch in the OS X finder.  Simplified, for that it either needs to be an OS X .app or its file type needs to be handled by an .app.

Comment: (To be clear, *that* in my comment above refers to the `chmod` suggestion.)

Answer (score 7):

The easiest thing to do is to type: **`sudo chmod 755 the_file_Name`**.This will allow you to double click on the file in the finder.

Answer (score 2):

With OS X 10.5+, you can [wrap the bash shell script in an `AppleScript` application](http://www.tuaw.com/2008/06/23/applescript-integrating-shell-scripts/) using the `AppleScript` editor or an `Automator` application using `Automator.app` (see the `Automator` on-line help).

You could write (and there are apps out there that do this) an OS X app that accepts arbitrary `.sh` files and executes them.  However, that's generally a bad idea as it could open you up to attacks if you inadvertently download a malicious shell script file that is automatically opened by your web browser.  Better to be explicit.