# How do i make this .sh file open on double click without using terminal?

Tags: applescript, sh

I have made a .sh program and i want it to open on double click.
My terminal can't open and there is no way to fix this.

Is there a way to make my program from script editor be able to open on double click without using terminal?

Thanks i would appreciate if it is possible.

Comment: If you would like to get an answer from someone you will need to provide more details like what OS you are using etc. Add some more details about the environment that you are operating in.

Comment: I have a macOS Sierra, version 10.12.6... Macbook air 2

Comment: Are any of the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538592/making-an-executable-bash-file-run-when-clicked) relevant?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making an executable bash file run when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538592/making-an-executable-bash-file-run-when-clicked)

Comment: No, none of the suggestions there actually work in my case... I can't download and run anything, just so you know, also the "sudo chmod 755 the_file_Name" command gives me an error. Is there any other suggestions?

Comment: @DuLacGaming You haven't really given us enough info to help here. Exactly why don't any of the linked suggestions work? Why can't you download & run anything? What error exact message does the `chmod` command give (and what if you leave off `sudo`)?

Comment: the sumo chmod 755 command gives out this: identifier cant be placed after identifier. if i remove sudo ,i get this: number cant be placed after identifier (using the sudo chmod 755 the file_Name command). i CAN download things, but for them to be put into applications it requires school admin name+password. if i drag the app i wanna download on to desktop and then run it, it will say that the admin has blocked this app. well technically it says you dont have permission to run this app. and my admin status is false. same problem with terminal and disk utility if that can be used for anything